# Javascript Canvas create Heart beat without requestAnimFrame

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to create a audio visualizer which is a canvas in heart beat shape. I have seen example like [on codepen](https://codepen.io/rlemon/pen/Ctayd). Please have a look at this. This example contains animations but i wanted it without the animation it should show me heard beat line/ pulse.

in codepen example :

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();
```

this function is creating animation. If i commented out the code is not working.

I dont want a heart beat animation in this it would static canvas 
    [this picture is my goal can anyone help me on this](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTTO5HUrY8EPvdh4pcAvbHnNH4WGSyLZrESLKDuXchz-gBcOMW6)

Comment: just change the x and y axis points

Comment: how can i remove animation ?

Comment: What you want is just a single still image of the heartbeat?

Comment: Nope I want that image to be filled by dynamic values. I don't want static that's why creating it from canvas. But i have two issue here one is animation which I don't want because animation is moving and gives fadding effect to the background

Comment: [Animation](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/animation) means to have the image change over time, so you can't have dynamic values without it. Do you mean that you want only the current position on the sinewave? Like a dot jumping up and down. Or perhaps you want less "history" in your graph and only show the part that is bright red in your example?

Comment: the static image which i have in the question which is https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTTO5HUrY8EPvdh4pcAvbHnNH4WGSyLZrESLKDuXchz-gBcOMW6 i want to create a canvas 100% like this. example of codepen is like Patient heart beat monitoring in realtime. i dont want that real monitoring (real montioring means it start an animation with darker red color and keep moving on. I dont want that). once i feed the values to canvas. It should look like the image mentioned above.